# Android freezes while sleeping - how to find why?

Tags: system-freeze

I can't wake up my Android DNS M83g tab from sleeping for several weeks. It freezes totally - pressing power button cause nothing to appear on screen, only holding it pressed for 10-20 sec helps to turn device off and then boot up from start. I can find nothing in logs using catlog since it shows only this time boot logs. Is there any known reason of the problem or could someone give me an advice to localize it (other then remove all recently installed/updated applications one by one and Factory data reset)?